# Mongo DB Full Text Search

Tags: mongodb, solr, full-text-search

Im running a MongoDB (2.6.1) instance and have several million documents e.g.

```
t.save( { _id: 1, title: "Physics World", caption: "Physics World is the membership magazine of the Institute of Physics."} );
t.save( { _id: 2, title: "A break away!", caption: "'A break away!' is an 1891 painting by Australian main writer Tom Roberts."} );
t.save( { _id: 3, title: "Mahim Bora", caption: "Mahim Bora (b.1926) is an Indian main writer and educationist from Assam state."});
```

I've also created an index e.g.:

```
t.ensureIndex( { caption: "text" } );
```

Then I search for the phrase "main writer" like this:

```
t.runCommand( "text", { search : "\"main writer\"", limit: 2000 } );
```

The problem I'm having is that Mongo only seems to return one record instead of two. If I load my data into SOLR and index it for full text search it works as expected.

Is there anything I could be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the text command you are running was deprecated in version 2.6:

> text
>
> Deprecated since version 2.6: Use $text query operator instead.

You should be using $text instead:

```
db.t.find({$text:{ $search : "\"main writer\""}}).limit(2000)
```

Don't know if that will make a difference in your specific case but using a deprecated command will make it difficult to debug and it definitely won't be supported in the future. When I tested this both versions worked but I only had 3 documents loaded, not the millions you have.

Comment: Just tried this from the mongo shell - same result. :(

Comment: I'd take you example data and query and run it against a collection with only 3 documents. If that works correctly it would point to either a bug or a problem with your index (which I would suggest in any event you try dropping and recreating).